# Why does filebeat try to connect to elasticseach?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

When running filebeat I get the below error:

> 2019-03-04T14:39:49.704Z  INFO    cfgfile/reload.go:205   Loading of config
>   files completed.
>   2019-03-04T14:39:50.709Z  INFO    pipeline/output.go:95   Connecting to
>   backoff(elasticsearch(http://localhost:9200))
>   2019-03-04T14:39:54.240Z  ERROR   pipeline/output.go:100  Failed to
>   connect to backoff(elasticsearch(http://localhost:9200)): Get
>   http://localhost:9200: dial tcp [::1]:9200: connectex: No connection
>   could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Which is really weird, because my filebeat is not configured to connect to elastic search:

(filebeat.config)

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - C:\my_Logs\*



output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

I cannot understand why this is happening, none of the tutorials I've followed mention elasticseach as a requirement, nor do any of the sample config files show anyone configuring the location.

Why is this happening and how can I disable this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason could very well be that your filebeat instance is not loading the config that you think it is.

The default [filebeat.yml](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/filebeat/filebeat.yml) has these lines:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  # Array of hosts to connect to.
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
```

Please check your config file.

**Update:** Additionally, filebeat has a command line option that allows you export the current configuration. This can be useful if you are uncertain what config it sees:

```
sudo filebeat export config
```

Link to the current docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/command-line-options.html#export-command